# PHP autoloading fails on other server

Tags: php, require, autoload

I've made a website module on localhost, and am trying to get it work on the live server, which is frustrating, as I'm sure that every class to be loaded has right syntax. They don't get loaded even though the path is the same.

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
   require("adk3/classes/".$class_name.".php");
}
```

The above was the original which worked on localhost executed from the root folder (htdocs/index.php)

```
function autoloader(){
       require("adk3/classes/".$class_name.".php");
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloader',true);
```

And this is which I was also trying and also didn't work. I've also checked absolute paths:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__)."/adk3/classes/".$class_name.".php");
```

The script stops execution at `$userList = new UserList();` without any error message even with `E_ALL` turned on. With the dirname syntax `file_exists()` says yes - they exist.

**Edit (additional info):**

- `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_ALL);`
  does not help anything at all.
- The PHP version is 5.3.1.
- `<?php
  require("adk3/interfaces.php"); // okay
  require("adk3/classes/UserList.php"); //STOPS without error shown`

Comment: Try running with `E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: Try running with parameter: function autoloader($class_name){
       require("adk3/classes/".$class_name.".php");
}
spl_autoload_register('autoloader',true);

Comment: wrap your dirname() in realpath() as well, it will return false if it can't resolve the path.

echo out the file name including path you are trying as well. If you get nothing, autoloader isn't running.

If it is returning the path to the file OK, autoloader is running. Wrap that in your realpath() and see if PHP can see that file :)

Comment: The server's PHP version does support `__autoload()`? And you are not using PHP in CLI interactive mode? `display_errors` is on (confirmed by `phpinfo()`)?

Comment: Did you confirm your autoload function is even running?

Comment: By its nature, it should be running when we call a class that's not defined yet.

Answer (score 1):

Took me ages to figure it out:

The files have been required successfully, that's why I never got any error message. The classes written in the required files were okay according to PHP5.4+. Since I had PHP 5.3 running on the new server, it couldn't interpret the new shorthand array syntax `[]`, which I used in some methods.